# Qt Signals and Slots not working inside of QObject

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals

I'm trying to create a client class for my API on the server, but my slot doesn't work after the request. The connect function returns true, which should mean that signal and slot are connected to each other.

`header file`

```
#ifndef QRESTCLIENT_H
#define QRESTCLIENT_H


#include <QObject>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>

class QRestClient : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit QRestClient(QUrl root_url, QObject *parent = nullptr);
    bool ping();

private:
    QUrl root_url;

private slots:
    void ping_finished(QNetworkReply * response);

};

#endif // QRESTCLIENT_H
```

`cpp file`

```
#include "qrestclient.h"

QRestClient::QRestClient(QUrl root_url, QObject *parent)
    : QObject{parent}
{
    this->root_url = root_url;
}

void QRestClient::ping_finished(QNetworkReply * response) {
    qDebug() << "It is here 3";
    qDebug() << response->readAll();
};

bool QRestClient::ping()
{
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    qDebug() << connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished,
            this, &QRestClient::ping_finished);

    qDebug() << "It is here 1";
    manager->get(QNetworkRequest(this->root_url));
    qDebug() << "It is here 2";
    return true;
};
```

I tried writing the same thing in the `mainwindow.cpp` file and it worked just as it should. In the case of requests from the `ping()` function of my class, I don't see any requests in server logs. If everything is the same from `mainwindow.cpp` I see the request in the logs. What is the problem, and why it does not send the request?

Comment: There's maybe a network related error. Connect all signals.

Comment: Also check the reply object returned by `get`

Comment: Note that `get` is not blocking. It simply sets up the request. You will get a reply on a later turn of the event loop. Can you show what the calling code looks like ? I have a suspicion your `QRestClient` object is being deleted before the event loop's current turn has ended.

Comment: @Botje Thank you for your replying, here is the calling code - https://github.com/markov404/stck_overflow_bug/blob/main/mainwindow.cpp

Comment: Please edit your question so the conversation is self-contained. The problem is as I expected: your `QRestClient` object is destroyed at the end of `on_find_btn_clicked` and the request is canceled.

Comment: @Botje Thank you, i will check now is it like you said or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Botje said, the problem was that QRestClient object is being destroyed at the end of calling code, before it is get the response. The solution is to put it in the private attributes of calling class.

Comment: That is *a* solution. You could also create the QRestClient on the heap with `new` and call `QObject::deleteLater` on your QRestClient in the `ping_finished` slot. Or after a timeout.